# Contracts Handling Incoming Transactions Without Receive/Fallback Functions

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-design

If a contract doesn't have a receive function nor a fallback function defined and the contract receives a transaction as a miner reward or a selfdestruct call, what does the contract do? Does the contract reject the transaction? Does it accept the transaction and update the balance of the contract?

Is there any difference to the above question if a fallback function exists but a receive function doesn't?